# Regex to restore VisualStudio Designer Code

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, decompiler

I have a C# project recovered from a decompiled VisualStudio project. I am trying to restore the .Designer.cs files but the formatting of the code in the decompiled files do not match the format that VisualStudio expects.

In particular I need to remove the use of the tempory variables. I am looking for a Regex expression that I can use in VisualStudio to do a search and replace to reformat the following type of code:

Replace:

```
Label label1 = this.Label1;  
Point point = new Point(9, 6);  
label1.Location = point;
```

With:

```
this.Label1.Location = new Point(9, 6);
```

Replace:

```
TextBox textBox5 = this.txtYear;  
size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 20);  
textBox5.Size = size;
```

With:

```
this.txtYear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 20);
```

etc.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense; visual studio should have no problem reading those code items.  Are you seeing error messages that you are trying to correct?

Comment: also, the items you posted aren't even equivalent.  The first would be assigning an object to a property of a control, the other would be setting a control equal to a different kind of object, which isn't valid.

Comment: You'd have a tough time writing regular expressions to do those replacements. I'm not saying it's not possible, but there'd be a lot of special cases and such. If you want to make changes like that, you need a real parser.

Comment: Visual Studio has no problem parsing the code as code. The issue comes when Windows Forms Designer tries to parse the code back into a visual representation for the designer. The parser doesn't recognize the use of the temporary variables. I have converted some of the forms manually but there are a number of forms with 100+ controls on them and it would be a huge effort to manually edit the code back to what designer will recognize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a regex replacement that works for the two examples you gave. I confirmed that it does the expected modifications in [this online .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

You will probably have to modify this regex further to suit your needs. For one thing, I am not sure how varied the code is within your file. If there is “normal” C# code mixed in with those three-line snippets, then this regex will just mess them up. You also didn’t specify how those three-line snippets are separated in the file, so you will have to edit the regex so it can find the start of the three-line snippet. For example, if all three-line snippets began with two Windows-format newlines, you could add `\r\n\r\n` to the start of the regex to detect those, and to the start of the replacement so they are preserved.

### Find regex

```
[^=]+=\s*([^;]+);\s*\n[^=]+=\s*([^;]+);\s*\n\w+(\.[^=]+=\s*)\w+;
```

Version with whitespace and comments:

```perl
[^=]+=\s*      # up to the = of the first line
([^;]+)        # first match: everything until…
;\s*\n         # the semicolon and end of the first line

[^=]+=\s*      # up to the = of the second line
([^;]+)        # second match: everything until…
;\s*\n         # the semicolon and end of the second line

\w+            # variable name (assumed to be the first line)
(\.[^=]+=\s*)  # third match: “.propertyName = ”
\w+            # variable name (assumed to be the second line)
;              # semicolon at the end of the line
```

### Replacement string

```
$1$3$2;
```

That adds up to the first line after the equal sign, then `.propertyName =`, then the second line after the equal sign, then an ending semicolon.